# Distribution of the Gram Matrices

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Let $\mathbf{X}$ be an $m\times m$ random matrix full rank matrix, having the density function $f_{\mathbf{X}}(X)$. Also, let $\mathbf{W}$ be a deterministic $k\times m$ matrix of rank $k$ and $k<m$. What is the distribution of $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{W}\mathbf{X}\mathbf{W}^T$? Basically my question is how to calculate the Jacoubian $|J(X→Y)|$.

Comment: unlike in your previous question, --- http://mathoverflow.net/questions/169041/distribution-of-the-gram-matrix --- you now have a linear transformation, so the Jacobian is constant and only affects the normalization of your distribution; so you don't really need it, but it's $$\left|\left|\frac{\partial WXW^{\rm T}}{\partial X}\right|\right|={\rm det}\,(WW^{\rm T})$$

Comment: Thanks Carlo. I still can not write the distribution of $\mathbf{Y}$ since the transformation from $\mathbf{X}$ to $\mathbf{Y}$ is not invertible. What is $f_\mathbf{Y}(\mathbf{Y})$?

Comment: you'll have to integrate over the degrees of freedom of $X$ that do not appear in $Y$; without knowing $f_X(X)$ there's no way to tell you what the outcome of the integration will give.